# How do i parse this JSON data?

Tags: ios, json

```
  ["api",["API","Apiales","Apiaceae","Apicomplexa lifecycle stages","Apia","Apicomplexa","Apidae","APIA Leichhardt Tigers","Apical consonant","Apical membrane"]]
```

How do i parse this JSON with SBJson Parser for iOS. i need it to be a array with only these values:

```
  "API","Apiales","Apiaceae","Apicomplexa   lifecyclestages","Apia","Apicomplexa","Apidae","APIA Leichhardt Tigers","Apical consonant","Apical membrane"
```

My current code:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

// Prepare URL request to download statuses from Twitter
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=dj&limit=100&namespace=0&format=json"]];

// Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

// Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *results = [json_string JSONValue];

NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
```

Comment: Do you need to support versions of iOS older than 5.0?  If not, you should consider using the JSON support added in iOS 5.  I used the SBJsonParser before then, and it is great, but I prefer to avoid dependency on third party libs, if I can avoid it.

Comment: Yes i need to use SBJsonParser for support of 4.1 etc. I can find a lot of example code but not how to parse my type of json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
NSArray *results = [json_string JSONValue];

NSArray *statuses = [results objectAtIndex:1];
```